# Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers (ADMM) application

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization

$\newcommand{\argmin}{\operatorname{argmin}}$
Recall, that ADMM algorithm solves the problem of the form:

$\min \text{ } f(X) + g(Z)$

$\text{s.t. } AX + BZ = C$

where $X$, $Z$ and $C$ are real matrices and both functions - $f$ and $g$ - are convex. The methodology is rather straightforward: write the augmented Lagrangian, update $X$ by minimizing it w.r.t. to $X$ while keeping $Z$ and $M$ (Lagrangian multiplier) constants; in a similar fashion update $Z$ and then update $M$. http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf here you can find all the necessary details.

Consider the following problem:

$\argmin \limits_P \text{ }\lambda \|X-PX\|_1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\|Y-P\|^2_F$

Where $Y$ and $X$ are given constant matrices and $\lambda$, $\beta$ are given constants. Let $J = X-PX$. Then we can write:

$\min_{P,J}\lambda \|J\|_1 + \frac{1}{\beta}\|Y-P\|^2_F$

$\text{s.t. } J+PX=X$

which is of the form ADMM is designed to solve.

Now, notice the role of $\lambda$ and $\beta_k$; they facilitate a trade-off between minimizing the first norm of $X-PX$ and getting closer to the matrix $Y$. Intuitively, they can be well-interpreted as respective weights.

Now, here is the thing I do not understand: let $\lambda=1$ and let's take two values of $\beta$: say, $\beta_1 = 0.1$ and $\beta_2 = 0.001$. Let the metric for convergence be the primal residual, namely, $R_k = J_k+P_kX-X$. Let's take a fixed number of iterations, say, 30. Then it turns out that the value of the convergence metric for these two different values of $\beta$ and a fixed number of iterations is different by a factor of more than 2.

To put in a different way: for the a smaller value of $\beta_k$ algorithm converges **perceptibly slower**. Why this is the case?

Update for $J$ is given by the soft thresholding operator with a threshold value given by $\lambda/\rho$, applied to $X-PX-\frac{M}{\rho}$, where $\rho$ is a constant in front of the extra term in the augmented Lagrangian (step-size for the $M$ update).

Update for $P$ is given by $P = (Y-\beta M X^T + (X-J)\beta \rho X^T)(I + \beta \rho X X^T)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Intuitively, what happens when $\beta\rightarrow 0$ ? Intuitively I would have guessed that it would converge faster, but apparently I'm wrong. I think this has something to do with the proximals operators in the update equations.

Comment: Are you using the same ADMM step size with both values of $\beta$?  How did you pick the ADMM step size?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what application does this problem arise in?

Comment: Bertrand, proximal operator is used for the update of J only; but as you can see now (sorry, I forgot to mention), beta_k is not involved there.

Comment: littleO, I vary penalty parameter to speed up the convergence; you can look it up if you follow the link I gave above, page 20.

Comment: Application of PRISMA to solving IRPCA.

Comment: Concerning a step-size. At the very beginning, I was playing with different constant values. Indeed, of course, by choosing a large rho value, you can achieve any desired level of precision, i.e. you can choose rho large enough to make the metric as small as you wish. However, of course, this comes with a price. As far as I understand - correct me if I am wrong - large values of rho decrease the precision of the solution since update of the Lagrangian is essentially a gradient ascent.

Comment: One comment -- ADMM is guaranteed (under mild assumptions) to converge for any step size you choose.  This means that with enough iterations, you should be able to get a solution that is as precise as you like with any step size, large or small.  (Getting a highly accurate solution with ADMM can take a very long time, whereas ADMM often converges quickly to a low or medium accuracy solution.)  I don't think there's a simple rule of thumb that large values of $\rho$ decrease the precision of the solution.

Comment: Assume that I take $\rho=10^{10}$. What kind of behavior would you expect? What if I take $\rho=10^{-10}$? How would you interpret the function of $\rho$?

Comment: If you ping me on kiryl.trembovolski@gmail.com, I can show you the plots I have made: on X axis different values of $\beta$, on $y-axis$ - value of the metric. $/lambda$ and number of iterations for all the experiments were fixed.

Comment: littleO, have u come across with LADM (Linearized ADM)?